# ¿Sintaxis al crear migraciones?

Tags: laravel, migration

Mi pregunta es corta , quiero saber si al crear una migracion debo poner

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

o puedo poner

```
php artisan make:migration crear_table_usuauarios
```

de igual manera al agregar un campo a una migracion ya hecha obligatoria mente debo poner

```
php artisan make:migration add_email_to_users
```

o tambien podria poner

```
php artisan make:migration agregar_email_tabla_usuarios
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CREAR UNA MIGRACIÓN PARA UNA NUEVA TABLA**

Si tu creas una migración con el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan make:migration crear_demo_table
```

Te va a crear un archivo de migración con la siguiente sintaxis

```
class CrearTableDemos extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

- El método `up()` esta vacío
- El namespace `Schema` no esta invocado dentro del método `up()` y por lo tanto tampoco invoca al método estático `create`
- Tendrás que declarar lo anterior por ti mismo
- Deberás colocar el nombre de la tabla que representa esta migración
- El método `down()` también aparece vacío es decir carece de esta línea `Schema::dropIfExists('tableName');`

Como dato también necesario fíjate que el nombre de la clase lo pone con el nombre que tu declaras en español que pudiera ser: `CrearTableDemos`

Entonces debemos considerar lo siguiente

- Cuando creas una migración con esta orientación: `create_tableName_table` Laravel de manera interna colocará lo siguiente
- El acceso al método create para recibir el nombre de la tabla
- La primer columna por defecto que se asume como `PK` y que es así: `$table->increments('id');` y también `$table->timestamps();`

> Como puedes observar crear una migración con `crear` y obtener un
>   archivo con la estructura base solo de la clase y los métodos `up()` y
>   `down()` equivale a escribir desde el inicio el contenido de tu
>   migración

**CREAR UNA NUEVA MIGRACIÓN PARA AGREGAR UNA COLUMNA A UNA TABLA EXISTENTE**

Ahora para el caso de agregar una columna a una tabla ya existente, si hacemos el siguiente comando

```
php artisan make:migration add_name_to_demos
```

Me va a dar como resultado

```
class AddNameToDemos extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('demos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('demos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

Ahora si en vez de `add` escribo `agregar` obtengo lo siguiente

```
class AgregarNameToDemos extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('demos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('demos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

De lo anterior extraemos que para una migración que servirá para crear una columna a una tabla ya existente, el resultado que obtendremos será el mismo, salvo por el nombre de la clase

Comment: osea que no importa si escribo en ingles o español tendré el mismo resultado?
 
es decir de esta manera **php artisan make:migration create_users_table**
o
de esta manera **php artisan make:migration crear_tabla_usuarios**
seria valido y tendia el mismo resultado?

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas podrás llegar al mismo resultado, pero presta mucha atención a todos los detalles que describí para cada escenario y determines cual conviene mas a tus intereses, por mi parte yo prefiero seguir las pautas marcadas por Laravel

Comment: hasta donde e leido en larvel y por lo que tu me dices  la manera correcta seria **php artisan make:migration create_usuarios_table --create=usuarios**

Comment: De hecho puedes omitir esto —create=usuarios

Comment: entonces esto **—create=usuarios** que funcion cumple

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas es para opcionalmente indicar el nombre de la tabla, pero incluso si no lo usas al momento de ejecutar la migración y solo haces esto: `php artisan make:migration create_users_table` el nombre que aparecerá en el método `create` será `users` por eso te comento es opcional

Comment: muchas gracias por tus aclaraciones has sido de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

No es obligatorio usar nombres con algún prefijo o formato. Puedes nombrarlas como quieras.

Solo se recomienda que uses nombres descriptivos para facilitar el mantenimiento del código.

Answer (score 0):

Debes ser bien claro con la nomenclatura por la que te estés rigiendo con tus tablas
En mi caso, estoy haciendo una con el prefijo **create_** :

```
create_nombre_de_la_tabla
```

Y viene más o menos así:

[image: Archivos en la carpeta migrations]

De igual forma, si te autogenera algún nombre que no quieras, puedes modificarlo directamente en el archivo.

```
Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('nombres');
        $table->string('apellidos');
        $table->string('username', 50)->unique();
        $table->string('contrasenia');
        $table->string('identificacion', 50)->unique();
        $table->string('e_mail', 50)->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('rol_id')->nullable();
        //$table->unsignedBigInteger('usuario_crea');
        $table->dateTime('creado_en')->default(new Expression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('usuario_modifica');
        $table->dateTime('modificado_en')->default(new Expression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->dateTime('eliminado_en')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('estado_eliminado');
        $table->foreign('rol_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
```

Comment: No hay necesidad de usar imagenes, el código se comparte como texto